# Streaming audio over serial using arduino

Tags: audio, arduino, serial-port

I read this link, its an updated code on Michael Smith's "speaker_pcm"
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=8817.0

it speaks about an application that streams audio over serial port,
the programmer did the receiving part saying this:

> The program on the remote host which supplies the audio data is **very simple to write** and could easily be done in most any programming language.

Any Ideas on how to make this simple remote host?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What host computer are you wanting to use and what programming language do you want the host written in?

Comment: Other than reading/decoding a byte and then outputting it via serial?

Comment: Dear mathew, Another arduino as a remote host that will send the serial audio thats been saved in memory.

Comment: Dear Ignasio, this is the issue, i copied the code in the link, and used the serial monitor to send the data to test the code, i sent the firsr 10 bytes manualy that represent length, then when trying to send other bytes (that represent the audio file ), i had the issue.

Comment: You don't send "bytes that represent the audio file", you send raw audio data.